# Capacitor Plugin for Ionic App in Kotiln Unresolved reference: Plugin

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have created a capacitor plugin and an Ionic app locally for development in two separate directories. Both the plugin and the app on Android are using Kotlin.

I am using

> Ionic Framework : @ionic/react 6.0.7
> Capacitor CLI      : 3.4.1
> @capacitor/android : 3.4.1
> @capacitor/core    : 3.4.1

I built the plugin, then linked it with `npm install ../capacitor/capacitor-my-plugin`

In Android studio when I go to the main activity I can register the plugin

```
package io.ionic.starter

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.plugin.MyPlugin

class MainActivity : BridgeActivity() {
  public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    registerPlugin(MyPlugin::class.java)
  }
}
```

I can click into the `MyPlugin` class and see that it is linked and all my code is there but when I run the application from the command line with `ionic capacitor run android` I get an error `Unresolved reference: MyPlugin`

I check and the `capacitor.settings.gradle` include my plugin

```
include ':capacitor-my-plugin'
project(':capacitor-my-plugin').projectDir = new File('../capacitor/capacitor-my-plugin/android')
```

In my javascript I've added a button to call my plugin

```
import { MyPlugin } from 'capacitor-my-plugin'

<IonButton onClick={(e) => MyPlugin.open({value: {value:""}})}>
  Activate
</IonButton>
```

If I remove the import and the registering in the main activity the app runs fine.

Comment: I do not think you need to register plugin in capacitor 3+ Remove the line " registerPlugin(MyPlugin::class.java)"  see if it works...

Comment: If I do that the code does build and run but the `init` function of the plugin is not called and the `@PluginMethod` isn't called when I call it from the javascript

Comment: Looks like you still need to register custom plugins https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#switch-to-automatic-android-plugin-loading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I converted the plugin to kotlin, Android Studio did not automatically add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` to the plugin's `build.gradle` file.